# Postman collection with multiple start points

Tags: postman

Determine which API to execute based on a field

I have a collection with 4 requests(say req1,req2,req3,req4) where inputs are parameterized. The input to the collection is a csv file. The csv file contains a field "type" based on which I would like to determine which is the first request I execute.

For eg. if type = 1 :order of execution :req 1, req3,req4

if type = 2 :order of execution :req 2, req3,req4

I am aware of how to modify the flow using the postman.setNextRequest(); but not sure of how this would work if the condition is for the first request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not feeling very comfortable with your approach. Because the setNextRequest() Workflow modifications are quite error prone. I would suggest to redesign this approach. Propably the pre-request-script or different Collections can be helpful?

However, you can try this solution asa a workaround. But ist quite hacky. I suppose, that the Test should stop after each of the four requests, and continue with the next iteration.

1. Add a dummy request to the collection and put it on the first position of your requests.
2. Add your if statements with the "setNextRequest()" commands in the test-code of this first "dummy" request.
3. Dont forget to add postman.setNextRequest(null) to each of the four requests, to prevent executing their successors.